# Upgrade from Rails 3 to Rails 4 - Issues with activerecord-sqlserver-adapter 4.1.0 and rails 4.1.4 "Rake Tasks Not Supported"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm trying to run rake tasks such as db:reset and getting the error "Rake tasks not supported by 'sqlserver' adapter."

I'm running ruby 2.1.2, rails 4.1.4, rake 10.3.2, and activerecord-sqlserver-adapter 4.1.0.

I've been using the adapter with Rails 3 and running db:reset without trouble, but now I'm trying to upgrade an app to Rails 4 and running into this problem. To isolate, I created an empty new Rails 4 app, added the adapter to the Gemfile, and updated database.yml to point to my SQL Server. I get the error above when I run rake db:reset.

I've tried setting up the workaround described in https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/wiki/Rails-DB-Rake-Tasks, with a minor adjustment to make it work with the latest versions of rake, but I still get the same error.

Am I doing something wrong, or is it just not possible to use tasks like db:reset with version 4 of rails and activerecord-sqlserver-adapter?

Comment: I can't get a rake db:create to work today either...

Answer (score 1):

"As of 2.3.6 of the adapter, we are now compliant with the rake task interfaces in the :db namespace of rails. That means for new unix-based developers that are working with a non-legacy DB, accurately reflected by schema.rb, can now use the standard rake tasks for just about everything except actually creating the development/test databases.

The only problem is that the we have not yet committed patches upstream to rails to remove Windows specific command interpolation from their databases.rake task. So, we have to do two things to get you up and running. First, here is an extension to Rake that allows us to method chain tasks."

https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/wiki/rails-db-rake-tasks